# How can I compute the total number of hours worked from database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a table name timelogTB and it has 5 column named; `LogID(PK),` `EmpNo(FK), Time_In, Time_Out` and Date running in form1.

Then in form2 I have a combobox where the Employee # of an employee can be selected and when I will select an Employee # the total number of hours worked of that employee will display in a textbox.

I have two date time picker the `dtpicker1` is labeled dtpFrom and `dtpicker2` is labeled dtpTo.

The column `Time_In` and `Time_Out` in `timelogTB` is only recording the time in military standard when the employee is time in using also a date time picker.

I am looking forward for a favorable answer guys, as much as possible I want you to explain it more simpler and precise because I am new in vb.net

thanks in advance!

Comment: By "military standard", do you mean like "13:30:00.000" or "1330"? If the former, you'd simply sum the `DATEDIFF` of the time_in and time_out (with a `WHERE` clause if you require it for a certain date period). e.g. `select sum(datediff(second, time_in, time_out) / 60.0 / 60.0) from mytable /* where date between myfirstdate and my second date */`. If the latter, you'd need to convert the values to `TIME` first (e.g. `cast(left(time_in, 2) + ':' + right(time_in, 2) as time(0))`) then do the same thing.

Comment: @ZLK  yes its the 1st one. Thank you very much, I will give it a try.

Comment: @ZLK, I have also the same problem with another code, this time its about total days worked.

Comment: Days would be a count of the distinct dates in the table. e.g. `select count(distinct date) from mytable /* where empno = abc and date between date1 and date2 */`

Comment: @ZLK, thank you very much sir. I will try this code and I hope when I'll ask again you will answer me again in short time. Thank you again and more power.

Comment: @ZLK, sir on your code for calculating the total days where should I put my column name Date_ to compute it.

Comment: After distinct eg select count(distinct mydate)...

Comment: @ZLK, sir the date1 and date2 in your will be my dtpFrom and dtpTo sir am I right?

Comment: between date1 and date2 would be the period of time you want it to be between. So whatever that is. date1 must be the earlier date because between only works if the first value is smaller than the second.

Comment: thank you very much sir. I will try this, and I will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function. Now just find a way to plug in your variables.

Comment: Can u give me sample codes on how will I extract it from the database?